# Publish data from HTML table to SAP table

Tags: javascript, abap

I have a Web contents table ZCOOKIES that published from SAP GUI. The table have 2 columns USER and PASSWORD, and a button:

[image: html table]

The button will push those DATA to table ZCOOKIES in SAP, how can I do it?

The ZCOOKIES table data in t-code SE16N:

[image: table]

The HTML and Javascript function for button that transfers those data to ZCOOKIES table:

```
<input type="button" style="width:5.740em" class="MobileButton " name="btnck[1]" 
 value="button" onclick="setOkCode('=BTNCK');" />
<script>
  function setOkCode(current) {
     var tr = $(current).parents("tr");
     var id = tr.find('.id').text();
     alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Since I don't think any possible way to push data from HTML to SAP? Any idea?

I'm coding in Web Application Builder (ITS) and ABAP is language to create table layout in SAP.

[image: ITS]

Comment: What software do you use? (SAPUI5, Fiori, ...) Why did you tag ABAP? NB: the screenshot is missing.

Comment: @SandraRossi I dont know what software actually cause I'm new to this, I'm coding in Web Application Builder in SAP, u can see this: [img](https://i.imgur.com/UiGb86F.png) and ABAP is language to create table layout in SAP .

Comment: [Cleartext passwords in a database table?!? Ewww!](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846)

Comment: I think ITS is the oldest ABAP Web technology, I hope there are people around who can answer.

Comment: Usually ITS pages need to be in sync with a dynpro in the backend (ZSPEC_DON_HANG_ALV_WEB/1001 in your case). Tabular data (<table> in HTML) should be transported through a step loop or table control

Comment: Or you could just call a webservice directly. I lost count of how many ways there are to create webservices on a SAP Netweaver system.

Comment: where does the edit occurs: in HTML frontend and then saved back to DB? this moment is unclear